# How to tabulate term fequency data with or without using document term matrix?

Tags: r, nlp, nltk, text-processing, text-analysis

I am trying to tabulated the following data:

Input

```
Big Fat Apple          3
Small Fat Apple        2
Little Small Pear      1
```

Expected output:

```
Big = 3
Fat = 3+2=5
Apple = 3+2=5
Small = 2+1=3
Little = 1
Pear = 1
```

I was trying to get document term matrix to treat this as corpus, but I am unable to find a way to do in a way that "Big Fat Apple" would be actually appearing in the corpus: "Big Fat Apple Big Fat Apple Big Fat Apple".

Is there any methods to do such tabulation? Ideally I would love to have it in the form of input into document term matrix so that I could use other functions.

Comment: did you try the package `tm` yet? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/

Answer (score 1):

To transform such a data frame into a corpus, you will have to tell it explicitly that each text should be reproduced x times, using `rep()`

```
d <- data.frame(
  text=c("Big Fat Apple",
         "Small Fat Apple",
         "Little Small Pear"),
  n = c(3,2,1),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(tm)
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(rep(d$text,d$n)))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
```

You can then compute terms frequency (see [How to find term frequency within a DTM in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28580460/how-to-find-term-frequency-within-a-dtm-in-r)).

Answer (score 1):

Using the sample data from @scoa's answer, you can try using `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package, like this:

```
> library(splitstackshape)
> cSplit(d, "text", " ", "long")[, sum(n), by = text]
     text V1
1:    Big  3
2:    Fat  5
3:  Apple  5
4:  Small  3
5: Little  1
6:   Pear  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest the [`quanteda` package](http://github.com/kbenoit/quanteda) (quantitative analysis of textual data).  What you want can be approached either by tokenising and tabulating, or by creating a document-feature matrix (here, with a single document):

```
cat("Big Fat Apple          3
     Small Fat Apple        2
     Little Small Pear      1\n", file = "example.txt")
mydata <- read.table("example.txt", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
mydata <- paste(with(mydata, rep(paste(V1, V2, V3), V4)), collapse = " ")
mydata
## [1] "Big Fat Apple Big Fat Apple Big Fat Apple Small Fat Apple Small Fat Apple Little Small Pear"

# use the quanteda package as an alternative to tm
install.packages("quanteda")
library(quanteda)
# can simply tokenize and tabulate
table(tokenize(mydata))
## apple    big    fat little   pear  small 
##     5      3      5      1      1      3 

# alternatively, can create a one-document document-term matrix
myDfm <- dfm(mydata)
## Creating a dfm from a character vector ...
## ... indexing 1 document
## ... tokenizing texts, found 18 total tokens
## ... cleaning the tokens, 0 removed entirely
## ... summing tokens by document
## ... indexing 6 feature types
## ... building sparse matrix
## ... created a 1 x 6 sparse dfm
## ... complete. Elapsed time: 0.011 seconds.
myDfm
## Document-feature matrix of: 1 document, 6 features.
## 1 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
## features
## docs    apple big fat little pear small
## text1     5   3   5      1    1     3
```

Happy to help with any questions you might have about `quanteda`, as we are actively seeking to improve it.